# How to select a checkbox with an attribute "checked" whose value is "checked" using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors, html-select

I'm currently doing some web scraping with selenium in Python. Now I want to select a check box which has a "checked" attribute with the value ""checked"", the part of that HTML is:

```html
<li class="private">
  <input id="inp-private" name="private" checked=""checked"" type="checkbox">
  <label class="pl" for="inp-private">仅自己可见</label>
</li>
<li>
  <div id="error" class="errnotnull"> </div>
</li>
```

I tried to use the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[checked = ""checked""]')
```

And the error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: 
Given css selector expression "input[checked = ""checked""]" is invalid: 
InvalidSelectorError: 'input[checked = ""checked""]' is not a valid selector: 
"input[checked = ""checked""]"
```

I first wonder if I should change the double quotation mark into single, but that doesn't work either.
*(The reason why I don't use other attributes is because they will return duplicate result, only the "checked" attribute is unique to the check box that I want.)*

So is there still a solution to select this attribute?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The HTML is invalid. The scaper probably can't handle that. A parser would presumably see this as `checked=""` first, and then `checked""`, which is bad.

Comment: So, the solution is to try to get the HTML in working order first. If that can't be done, pray that the scraper has parsed the value of the `checked` attribute as `""`.

Comment: @MrLister Do you mean that the `checked=""checked""` part is invalid?

Comment: Yes, that's the invalid part. If I paste that into a HTML file and look at the resulting DOM in the browser, it says `<input id="inp-private" name="private" checked="" checked""="" type="checkbox">`

Comment: @MrLister I got it! So maybe I can try to use `input[checked = ""]`, according to what the parser sees.

Comment: @MrLister  Well, just tried, that still doesn't work, the HTML code itself is not okay...

Answer (score 1):

Well the great thing about selenium is that you can save certain element findings store them in a variable and then do another find_element request to actually dig deeper.

This is a great way to filter though elements and get to certain attributes.
I don't know the full HTML code of the page you are looking at but for sake of argument in this case you could grab the attribute value that you are looking for by doing the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver;
browser = webdriver.Firefox();
browser.get(yourpagehere);
container_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('private');
target_element = container_element.find_element_by_tag_name('input');
grab_attribute = target_element.get_attribute('checked');
```

By doing the following we first grab the main element containing the element we wish to target for its attribute.
This element has the class name private.

Once we have that element stored in a variable called container_element, we can conduct another find element search on the element we just saved and grab its child element with the input tag and store that to another variable called target_element.

Finally we can now access that element and all its attributes by just calling target_element.get_attribute(attributehere).

This always seems to work for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, just tried it on my machine, if the page has that checkbox, it will return a `u'true'` . This method is really helpful !!

Comment: Just curious, why the value "checked" is surrounded by double layer of quotation marks?? Is that an error?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be. There is no way of looking at it that it could be considered correct.

Comment: @MrLister But the interesting part is...this is a real website and the checkbox works well, that's why I find it strange.

Comment: @lleiou Probably because all browsers handle this in roughly the same way: they see `checked=""` first, which sets the `checked` attribute, and then `checked""`, which is simply discarded as an error. The end result is the same.

Comment: That said, you should never rely on browsers handling errors in the same way. In many cases, the end result is different in different browsers.